# How to execute select() method on polymer elements based on URL?

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer, paper-elements

I've a paper-menu with links

```
<paper-menu>
  <a href="/home">Home</a>
  <a href="/about">About</a>
</paper-menu>
```

When I click any link, Polymer adds a .iron-selected CSS class to it, but if occurs a page reload or a page redirect, I lose the CSS class.

My question is: how can I do Polymer add that class based on URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the tips Ryan!

My solution was:

```
document.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function(){
    var menu = document.querySelector('paper-menu')
    var paths = menu.items.map(function(item){
        return item.pathname
    })
    window.setInterval(function () {
        menu.select(paths.indexOf(location.pathname))
    }, 100);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see a working example [here](http://output.jsbin.com/cekuda)

When you go to the page "cekuda", the cekuda menu item is selected,
When you go to the page "jegano", the jegano menu item is selected.

- Use the global variable "location" to check the url of the page.
- Wait until the "WebComponentsReady" event has fired before trying to do anything to the paper-menu.
- Analysis the paper-menu children through [paper-menu.items](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-menu#property-items)
- Add the class to the element that is to be selected using [paper-menu.select](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-menu#method-select)